# vscode formatting a list variable with many elements

Tags: python, list, visual-studio-code, formatting

I currently have this list:

alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

when I run my code in VSCode, it would format my list to below. How do I avoid this formatting of one element per line? Is there a way that it would show the list in 2-3 lines instead of 28 lines?

```
alphabet = [
    "a",
    "b",
    "c",
    "d",
    "e",
    "f",
    "g",
    "h",
    "i",
    "j",
    "k",
    "l",
    "m",
    "n",
    "o",
    "p",
    "q",
    "r",
    "s",
    "t",
    "u",
    "v",
    "w",
    "x",
    "y",
    "z",

]
```

Comment: disable format on save

Comment: I would like to keep the format on save to adhere to pep8

Comment: let the linter warn you of non-pep8 cases, after a while you type the code pep8 compliant

Answer (score 1):

You could use `string.ascii_lowercase` to avoid having a hardcoded list like that:

```
import string
alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase
```

```
>>> alphabet
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

This accomplishes your problem in 2 lines with many fewer characters

If you would like a list of the elements you can typecast it like so:

```
alphabet = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
```

[See further documentation here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html)

Comment: yes, this will work for this case. However, what if the elements are not alphabet?